# Bulk Insert data conversion error with CSV file in SQL Server for BIT datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, bulkinsert

I am trying to load data from CSV to table with BULK INSERT functionality.
In file for one column values are as True and False as the column datatype is BIT in database.

However when I tried to import it thrown an error as below.

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 2 (ISTrue).

Here is the code which I have used for data import.

```
    BULK INSERT dbo.BulImportTesting
    FROM 'C:\ExportData\Test\dbo_tbl_Import.csv'
    WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,
          FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
          ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
          BATCHSIZE = 100000,
          KEEPIDENTITY);
```

Here is the sample data I am trying to import

```
ID      UseStartDate
81958   FALSE
81959   FALSE
83336   FALSE
83337   FALSE
83338   TRUE
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: `bit` is not boolean, it's just a one digit number, it can either be 0 or 1

Comment: I have exported this data from another table that has bit datatype and it converted to TRUE/FALSE instead of 0/1.

Comment: Query the file with `OPENROWSET(BULK ` and you can provide conversions and translations before INSERTing the data in the target table.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - If possible, could you please provide an example for the same?